# Hide or avoid the PowerShell Script return the error message

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to have a  PowerShell Script to check the task scheduler. If the task name exists then delete it.

```
if (schtasks /query  /tn "mytask") {
    schtasks /delete /tn "mytask" /f | Out-Null
}
```

The syntax works well when the user has the task name in the task scheduler. However, the PowerShell returns the error message when the task name doesn't exist:

```
schtasks : ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:5
+ if (schtasks /query  /tn "mytask") {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The syst...file specified.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Is there any way to avoid or hide the PS return the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the stream [redirection operator `>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) to supress errors from `schtasks`:

```
if(schtasks /query  /tn "mytask" 2>$null){
    schtasks /delete /tn "mytask" /f | Out-Null
}
```

But I would personally prefer using `Get-ScheduledTask` from the [`ScheduledTasks` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/), then use the `-ErrorAction` common parameter to ignore any errors:

```
if(Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "mytask" -ErrorAction Ignore){
    Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName "mytask" -Confirm:$false | Out-Null
}
```